# Codeigniter Session Manipulation

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm building a system in Codeigniter 3.

Now as an admin user, i want to have the ability to login as a customer, so basically see what they see when they login.

Is it possible to manipulate the session within Codeigniter to allow an admin user to login to a different users account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's question of how you build your app. I would make a switch which sets the session variable - f.e. "see_as_user" = 1, and than on the layout check this variable. Basically you should take control over what user sees.